# Find intersecting values from repeating groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Running `SQL Server 2012`. Consider this value set:

```
ID    Status
------------
11    0
11    1
11    2
12    0
12    1
12    2
13    1
14    2
```

**How do I retrieve the intersecting status values grouped on the ID?**

I.e. Since `ID=13` only has `Status=1` and `ID=14` only has `Status=2`, the data above would result in an empty row:

```
Status
------
```

However, If we remove `ID=14`, the result would be:

```
Status
------
1
```

And if we remove `ID=13` too, the result would be:

```
Status
------
0
1
2
```

### UPDATE

The problem needs to be solved for an arbitrary number of `ID` with an arbitrary number of `Status` values. Hence, two `SELECT` queries is not enough (even though it might work for the test data above).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) problem.

Using the double `NOT EXISTS` approach returns all if dividing by an empty set.

```
DECLARE @S TABLE (
  [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @S
VALUES      (11),
            (12)

SELECT DISTINCT [Status]
FROM   YourTable Y1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   @S
                  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM   YourTable Y2
                                     WHERE  Y1.[Status] = Y2.[Status]
                                            AND Y2.ID = [@S].ID))
```

Comment: Interesting! This, however, seems to return the greatest common value set (e.g. `0, 1, 2`) whereas I'm looking for the least common value set (e.g. empty row).

Comment: I'm wondering if using `PIVOT` is a reasonable idea. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @l33t - That isn't what your question says! It says start with `14,13` returns nothing, remove `14` returns 1 row. Remove `13` so you have an empty set and it returns everything. Well the `GROUP BY ... COUNT` from the linked article will do what you need for  dividing by an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

This select should work for any values:

```
select distinct status
from a a1
where (select count(distinct id) from a) = (select count(distinct id) from a a2 where a2.status = a1.status)
```

Here is a complete script that works with the example numbers in your question:
    create table a (id int, status int)

```
insert a values (11, 0)
insert a values (11, 1)
insert a values (11, 2)
insert a values (12, 0)
insert a values (12, 1)
insert a values (12, 2)
insert a values (13, 1)
insert a values (14, 2)

select distinct status
from a a1
where (select count(distinct id) from a) = (select count(distinct id) from a a2 where a2.status = a1.status)

delete a where id = 14

select distinct status
from a a1
where (select count(distinct id) from a) = (select count(distinct id) from a a2 where a2.status = a1.status)

delete a where id = 13

select distinct status
from a a1
where (select count(distinct id) from a) = (select count(distinct id) from a a2 where a2.status = a1.status)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know about the IDs beforehand. The data I presented was just example data. What I need is some `GROUP BY` or `INTERSECT` magic.

Comment: It will work with any IDs but I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest (and most readable) one would be to do it like this:

```
select t.status
from Table1 as t
group by t.status
having count(distinct t.id) = (select count(distinct t2.id) from Table1 as t2)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1c213/4)</kbd>**